# Button_to patch method is unexpectedly working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was struggling the whole day to make my button_to working. This is the code in my order index view:

```
<%= button_to("Remove", {:controller => "orders", :action => "update", :id => product.id}, :method => :patch) %>
```

my controller  :

```
  def update
    @order.products.delete(Product.find(@product.id))
    @product.ordinable = true
    @product.save
    @order.amount = 0
    @order.save
    @order_amountnew = @order.amount
    @order.products.each do |x|
    @order_amountnew = @order_amountnew + x.price
      end
    @order.amount = @order_amountnew
    @order.save
    if @order.products.empty?
      @order.destroy
    end
    redirect_to orders_url
  end
```

and my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  devise_for :users
  resources :products
  resources :orders, only: [:show, :create, :index, :destroy, :update]
  post '/payment', action: :payorder, controller: 'orders'
  patch '/orders', action: :update, controller: 'orders'

  require "sidekiq/web"
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
end
```

I was trying to trigger the code inside the update method using the button_helper inside my order index. I come up with this solution and unexpectedly my button_to method now trigger the update method, but only after i  spent hours googling and added to my routes this line of code:

```
patch '/orders', action: :update, controller: 'orders'
```

My question is now, whenever i want to trigger a method with a link_to or a button_to, i must create a route for each method like that right? Otherwise, i get routing error right? I have this doubt because here:

```
resources :orders, only: [:show, :create, :index, :destroy, :update]
```

i already defined an update route for my orders resource, so i don't understand why i need to specify again the route for the crud method i want to use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `resources :orders, only: [:show, :create, :index, :destroy, :update]` will yield update url as **/orders/:id**. You can verify that by poking in `rake routes` output.
2. `patch '/orders', action: :update, controller: 'orders'` yields update url as **/orders**.

The reason why latter works is because `<%= button_to("Remove", {:controller => "orders", :action => "update", :id => product.id}, :method => :patch) %>` send a request to **/orders?id=...**. You can verify that in the stacktrace

If you want to use 1, you should change `button_to` to format like `<%= button_to("Remove", product_path(product), :method => :patch) %>`. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to for references.

Hope that helps :).

Comment: I tested this button_to and it works fine too: <%= button_to("Remove", orders_path, params: {:id => product.id}, :method => :patch) %>. Compared to my first solution,  basically, the fact that i don't need to specify the controller anymore is because the orders_path is pointing of course automatically to the orders controller, and the :method => :patch look straight for the crud method update content right? Without the need to specify the :action => "update", am i right? And by the way, when i use action? For non crud methods right? Thank you